# Is this a rare/variant character (combining 米 and 団), or not really a Chinese character?

Tags: character-identification, taiwan

[image: 米+団 character]

This character is on [the label of a riceball sold at 7-11](http://www.7-11.com.tw/2week/111228/app_111228-3.png) in Taipei. I believe this kind of riceball is originally Japanese.

It seems to be some kind of variant of 糰 / 团 but is actually composed of 米 on the left plus 団 on the right. But I can't find it anywhere on the Internet or in Unicode so far.

Is it a known variant, or is it possibly normally considered a Japanese character? On Wiktionary, 団 is listed only as a Japanese shinjitai character. (Shinjitai is a simplified character made in Japan.)

Or maybe it's some kind of fake character made up by 7-11, like a trademark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

糰 is 米 + 團. 團 simplified is 团. 团 has a variant character 団.

Thus 米 + 団 = 糰.

団 itself is a variant chacter of 糰.

On the other hand it could just be a clever way of writing 米團 = 米团 = rice ball.

Edit: It is written 御飯團 in all instances I can find regarding the ad. It is a private/funny simplification that has no formal recognition.

Comment: And 米團 / [米团](https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E7%B1%B3%E5%9B%A2) is pronounced "mǐtuán".

Comment: http://yedict.com/zscontent.asp?uni=1G3170